# Who manned the Beacons of Minas Tirith?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

In both Tolkien’s and Jackson’s *The Lord of the Rings* there are beacons for Gondor to call for aid in times of need. Only in the Peter Jackson film of *Return of the King* do the beacons go from Gondor to Rohan but is there a name for the people manning them or are they 'employed' from the local area? E.g. In the books the Red Arrow took the message to Rohan and not the beacons so is there a term similar to those who light the warning fires?

Comment: I read the answers but never noticed a definitive answer to who the 'lighters of the beacons' were (or did I miss it?

Comment: I think the answer is just random people assigned beacon duty.

Comment: @JamesDouglas did you read the 'do the beacon lighters...' Question? If you agree with my comment please vote to reopen or tell me I can't read! Was watching Thronecast at the time (smile). Thanks

Comment: Tbh I don't personally think that this is a dupe, but maybe the people who marked it know better. Maybe the other question's answers contain all known info about the beacons.